# Can Apple Mail be optimized to perform well when I have 30k messages in my inboxes?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have about 31,300 emails in 4 different inboxes in Mail. Sadly to say, it is extremely slow.

Is there any tips or trips to optimize Mail?  And no, I don't want to delete any, I need them for work.

Comment: What kind of hard drive do you use?

Comment: Uh, whatever is in my 24" iMac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is clean up the index file Mail uses to track the messages:

```
  sqlite3 ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope\ Index vacuum;
```

Thanks for this [tip to the estimable Brett Terpstra](http://brettterpstra.com/vacuuming-your-mail-app-index-still-works-wonders/). The linked article explains how to make an AppleScript file to measure things before and after to see if the operation thinned out the size of the file Mail uses to store the pointers to the messages. I would add, quit Mail and make a backup before trying to clean the file. A `vacuum` operation is normally harmless, but why not get a backup just in case.

Also, this thread probably goes back to [@bbum and his weblog-o-mat](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2007/03/02/vacuuming-mails-envelope-index-to-make-mail-faster/) and perhaps even deeper back...

Comment: Joshua- Awesome! That was driving me crazy and mail is running blazing fast again. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For me the sqlite3 vacuum didn't speed Mail.app back up.

The thing that returned my Mail.app to blazing fast speeds was deleting the mail sandbox folder.

1. Quit Mail.app
2. Delete the folder `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail` (use `rm -r ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail` from Terminal, or in Finder press <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd>, enter `~/Library/Containers` then find the `com.apple.mail folder` and drag to trash and empty trash)
3. Relaunch Mail.app

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/20662231#20662231

Comment: Great! The only disadvantage for me was the reset of the Mail.app UI. The speed is incredible now.